# Efficiently rebalancing a tree of 2^n-1 nodes?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, asymptotic-complexity

I stumbled upon this question: 
Given a binary search tree with 2^n-1 nodes, give an efficient algorithm to convert it to a self balancing tree(like avl or RB tree). and analyze its worst case running time as a function of n.

well I think the most efficient algorithm is at o(n) time for n nodes, but the 2^n-1 nodes is the tricky part. any idea what will be the running time then?

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got a linear-time algorithm for solving this problem, great! Think of it this way. Let m = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1. If you have an algorithm that balances the tree and runs in time linear in the number of nodes, then your algorithm runs in time O(m) in this case, which is great. Don't let the exponential time scare you; if the runtime is O(2<sup>n</sup>) on inputs of size 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, then you're running efficiently.

As for particular algorithms, you seem to already know one, but if you haven't heard of it already, check out the [Day-Stout-Warren algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm), which optimally rebuilds a tree and does so in linear time and constant space.